# Magento 2 modify table value in admin form by uiComponent

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform

I have created a custom admin form by UI component that has a field which looks like this:

```
<field name="column_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Field Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">source_name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">column_name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

DB Table contains value like this: `some-file-name.pdf`

I want this to be shown as an anchor downloadable link in the admin form field like:

```
<a href="Magento_Root/pub/media/some-file-name.pdf>FIle Name</a>"
```